# Regex to find a pattern of string between slashes

Tags: php, regex, laravel, pattern-matching, regex-negation

I'm looking for the right way to build the regex for this:

I have these sites and I need cut the word **string** or **whatever have between** slashes.
Using the https://regexr.com/

I had this result. Someone can help me?

```
http://example.com/string/anotherThings
http://example.com/string/anotherThings
http://example.com/string_string/anotherThings
```

[image: example]

Comment: `\/\w+\/g` ? ? ?

Comment: There's a way to cut the slashes too?

Comment: Why don't you group `\w+`? `\/(\w+)\/` or use `(?<=\/)\w+(?=\/)`

Comment: I would use explode instead of a regex for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If there are multiple slashes in the url, do you wish to retrive the shortest part or the whole part, like this:
  `https://test.com/page/number/1`, which one do you actually want?
- If it's `page/number`, the regex should be `(?<=\/)[\w_\]+(?=\/)`
- If it's `page`, `number`, try `(?<=\/)[\w_]+(?=\/)`

Comment: `[\w_\]+` can be replaced with `\w+`.